# app developed in android studio and python and Chaquopy

Tags: python, opencv

I'm making an app on robot themes in java in android studio environment and I have to implement the face recognition in python using the library Chaquopy I tried to include these libraries:

`python { pip { install "six" install "opencv-python" install "numpy" install "face-recognition" } }`

But they give me error that is : "Read error: ssl=0x87d83d8: I/0 error during system call, Connection timed out SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xb87d83d8: I/0 error during system call, Broken pipe" they don't allow me to launch the 'app even if it is downloaded ... is it possible?